# Circular ProgressBar unwanted spacing

Tags: android, android-progressbar

In my layout there is `ProgressBar` with

```
android:layout_width="30dp"
android:layout_height="30dp"
```

No `margins` or `paddings` set.
But `ProgressBar` does not occupy whole bounding box, strange gap present around the circle.

[image]

How can I make `ProgressButton` fit specified sizes?

Comment: Try setting left and right padding as 0dp

Comment: create custom spape and set `android:innerRadiusRatio="2"` that way you do not see a gap. Just play with that variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

you can use `android:clipChildren="false"` to make it overflow on parent

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clipChildren="false">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="50dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ProgressBar
            android:layout_width="390dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginLeft="55dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="50dp" />
    </LinearLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```